# azure web sites, Keep getting error: Could not connect to the Local Git repository

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

i setup a azure website in free tier,  and also in the management portal, setup the deployment from source control, then in following screen, ask where is your source code,  , i select [Local Git repository].

After the setup, yesterday i was able to go to the deployment tab of that website in the management portal , it shows the information about the `git` url .

this morning, i went to the deployment tab, then i got an error:

```
Could not connect to the Local Git repository.
```

The details says:

`Scm service error is "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).`

Any idea?

Here is the steps i followed.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

The "the Local Git repository" in the error message, does that mean the local git on my local computer?  As i understand, i should push my local git on my computer to azure, why would azure try to connect to my local git ? There is no way, right?

Comment: I dont use visual studio.  I set up the website deployment using local git .  Then i could push my local git on my local computer to azure. I don't think the azure will connect to my local git on my local computer.

Comment: .NET 3.5 not supported for the git deployment is not documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the cause is that the website is configured using .NET 3.5,  which is not working properly for git deployment right now

It is answered here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/1aae2b9a-53b3-4ea9-812f-85da0db75c92/keep-getting-error-could-not-connect-to-the-local-git-repository?forum=azuregit

Answer (score 0):

In this section (on the page you reference above):

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/#Step6

you create a remote for your local repo.  That remote is within Azure Websites.  It is this remote repo that is being referred to as Local Repo by the error message.  It looks to me like you have a credential problem, based on the 403.